# WordPress - Insert default category if category not selected

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having category list in checkbox list format and i have to insert default category value which is "Uncategorized" if category is not selected by user. i'm trying with something like below;

```
$category = (isset($R_data['category']) ? $R_data['category']:'Uncategorized');
```

But **Null** record getting added in to the database.

Comment: replace `isset`  with `is_null`

Comment: If i remember correct wp uses select for categories as default so, i suggest you to set default select option to "Uncategorized"(or whatever you desire). This way it will insert that selection to database.

Comment: You can also use `(empty($R_data['category']) ? $R_data['category']:'Uncategorized');` but I'll go with @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz approach

Comment: hi @madalinivascu, **is_null** does not worked

Comment: @OluwafemiSule, even **empty** statment not working

Comment: @GlenDavidson try using in_category() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/

Comment: Try `!empty`  `$category = (!empty($R_data['category']) ? $R_data['category']:'Uncategorized');`

Comment: Thank @AnkurBhadania. My logic was warped...lol

Comment: @all - let me tell you guys i'm having custom category table

Comment: thank you both of you, @OluwafemiSule and AnkurBhadania, yours solution worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$category = (!empty($R_data['category']) ? $R_data['category']:'Uncategorized');
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation of how your answer solves the original question.  Just putting code may help solve a problem, but it doesn't help understand the problem better.